# iOS 12 - IPA size decreased significatly

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ipa

I  was building new `.ipa` file today for  one of our applications and i noticed  a significant decrease  in its size compared to the last version (about 12 MB) .
we did not change anything since the last build except for the SDK version as we updated to 12.0 .

- Have anyone noticed a similar behavior with SDK 12.0
- Did Apple mention  that The new SDK version will affect the `.ipa` size ?

Comment: I have not noticed such differences in our product when building to iOS 12 - Are you sure there are no changes in included assets, fonts or similar? I recently shaved off 9mb by removing a 80k LoC dependency, so 12MB is a major difference.

Comment: @OscarApeland no assets  fonts, or pods were removed .. that's why i'm finding this a bit  weird

Comment: I havn't heard about any changes either. My best guess would be to read trough [the release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes) and see if anything there might've affected your product.

Comment: Also, try posting about this on reddit. There's a better community of developers for these things there.

Comment: @OscarApeland Thanks , i will try that .  i'm not complaining ( so far) , let's just hope this won't trigger a panic attack  for our client